# output repetition

Tags: python

I wrote this program which outputs pythagorean triplet whose sum is a certain number(this would be the parameter). The program runs perfectly but the same triplet is appearing multiple times and I want one triplet to appear just once. I was wondering if someone could help me out. Thanks!

```
def pythagoreanCheck(tripletList):
    '''
        Checks whether the three numbers are pythagorean triplet
        returns True or False
    '''

    trip_list = [0,1,2]

    if tripletList[0]**2 + tripletList[1]**2 == tripletList[2]**2:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def givMeSum(target):
    '''
        returns 3 numbers such that their sum is equal to target
    '''       

    listOfa = xrange(1,target)
    listOfb = xrange(1,target)
    listOfc = xrange(1,target)

    for i in listOfa:
        for j in listOfb:
            for k in listOfc:
                add = i + j + k

                if add == target:
                    add_list = [i,j,k]
                    add_list.sort()

                    value = pythagoreanCheck(add_list)

                    if value:
                        print add_list


def main():
    givMeSum(12)

main()
```

Comment: Ask yourself: what values can `i`, `j` and `k` take in your code? For a given pythagorean triplet `a`, `b`, `c`.. is `(a,b,c)` different than `(b,a,c)` ?

Comment: What purpose does `trip_list = [0,1,2]` serve?

Comment: @Eric: I think I was doing something else but forgot to delete it. It serves no purpose.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're doing your calculations in a nested list and then creating a sorted list of 3 different permutations of the same numbers.

Since i, j, and k will enter different combinations of the same three numbers 3 times, add will equal target each time, which means that add_list is created and sorted 3 times. Which means that it will create the same list 3 times.

I think that you should just take out

```
add_list.sort()
```

And Siddharth is right, your algorithm is really inefficient. You're turning it into an O(n^3) algorithm, which could take a really long time with larger target numbers.

Comment: oh Thanks, I think I got it. Yeah its not that efficient but it served the purpose. How can I make it better?

Answer (score 0):

1. Consider storing each tuple in a hash table (dictionary)instead of printing it within the innermost loop. At the end of all the loops completion, print all the values in the hash.
2. Aside from your question, you can make the algo faster by creating a hash of integers and replace the innermost loop with a hash search.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that `i <= j <= k`:

```
def pythagoreanCheck(tripletList):
    '''
        Checks whether the three numbers are pythagorean triplet
        returns True or False
    '''
    a, b, c = tripletList
    return a**2 + b**2 == c**2

def givMeSum(target):
    '''
        returns 3 numbers such that their sum is equal to target
    '''       

    for i in xrange(1, target):
        for j in xrange(i, target):      # j >= i
            for k in xrange(j, target):  # k >= j   
                if i + j + k == target:
                    add_list = [i, j, k]  # no need to sort any more

                    if pythagoreanCheck(add_list):
                        print add_list


def main():
    givMeSum(12)

main()
```

As noted, this algorithm is far from optimal, but this will at least solve the problem you're seeing.

Here's a slightly better way (two nested loops instead of three):

```
def giveMeSum(target):
    '''
        returns 3 numbers such that their sum is equal to target
    '''    
    for i in xrange(1, target):
        for j in xrange(i, target):
            k = target - i - j
            if k < j:
                break  # skip to the next value of i - all remaining js are too big

            add_list = [i, j, k]

            if pythagoreanCheck(add_list):
                print add_list
```

Comment: I think that this algorithm requires the input array to be sorted in increasing order before giveMeSum() is invoked.

Comment: @SiddharthToshniwal: Which input array?

Comment: Yeah its not that efficient but it served the purpose. How can I make it better? I forgot that I had to make sure i < j < k

Comment: @Cheetahjimi: Why loop for all `i`, `j`, and `k`, when you know they sum to `target`? You can calculate `k = target - i - j` and check that meets the k >= j condition

Comment: @Cheetahjimi: What are you talking about? `i` and `j` are not calculated in terms of `k`.

Comment: @Eric. How can you calculate then i and j? because the sum of i, j, and k has to be 1000. Plus they have to be pythagorean numbers not just random.

Comment: @Cheetahjimi: Instead of iterating over all `i`, `j`, and `k` for `i < j < k and i + j + k == target`, iterate over all `i` and `j`, and calculate `k` as `target - (i + j)`. See my edit.